# What happen in if else statement?

Tags: ios

I have wondered what happens in an if else statement.  For example, in the logic below I have a catch all `else` statement at the bottom that is executed if the user has neither set up TouchID or a PIN code for login.

1) Will the else statement take up any system resources if either, `if statement` above is evaluated as true OR false?

2) There seems to be several ways of sending a user to a viewcontroller, you can have `presetViewController()` and `performSegueWithIdentifier()`.  Which is the "correct" method?

```
  func chooseTouchIDorPINLayout(){

        if touchIDBtn == 1{
            //do something

        }else if touchIDBtn == 2{
            // do something else

        }else{
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let onboardingNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("onboardingNavigationController")
            self.presentViewController(onboardingNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Any input is much appreciated - thank you !

Comment: you definitely must read something about Refactoring

Comment: sage444 yeayhyeahyeah, this was just a question about how system resources is effected by if else statements.  I have clarified code.

Comment: Can it not be nil? I changed the code so as not to distract from the actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, when a condition is evaluated as true the rest of the expression is skipped.
2. There is no correct method. It depends:

   - If the transition is designed in Interface Builder via a segue, use `performSegueWithIdentifier`.
   - If the transition is designed in code, use `presentViewController`

Comment: #2) Ok, so they are basically the same, if I have a choice should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: I'd always prefer the Interface Builder / segue way if possible

Answer (score 0):

About if statements,
If the condition is true the interpreter skips the else statements and doesn't use system resourses